# NextJS automatically replace <img/> tag to <Image/> Component

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I have the Problem, that I fetch HTML (and md) from a headless CMS (Directus).
The Problem is that the Images are not optimized.
How can I automatically replace all fetched  tags with Next`s Image-Component?

This is how I fetch the Html Code:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: data.path} }></div>
```

This is how I fetch MD:

```
<ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}>
  {data.path}
</ReactMarkdown>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems that you could get away with using the html syntax tree plugin (called "hast") from the overarching "unified" project (which is where "rehype" is from), see https://github.com/syntax-tree/hast

Still, I only want to replace "img" tags with NextJS "Image" tags, and sometimes "a" tags with NextJS "Link" tags. I don't want to have to parse the entire markdown structure for everything else...